# @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to use viewmodel and observe the data in my DialogFragment, I'm Injecting ViewModel as well, while implementing the code getting error. PFB my code snippet. And help me out with suitable solution.

1. Current DialogFragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MyFragmentFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_buycourse, container, false);
        myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);

        view = mBinding.getRoot();

        initViews();

        return view;
    }

    public static MyFragmentFragment newInstance(){
        return new MyFragmentFragment ();
    }
}
```

2. Parent Fragment in code

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     
        mBinding.startBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogFragment dialog = new MyFragmentFragment ();
            dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.Theme_Learn365_NoActionBar);
            dialog.show(requireActivity().getFragmentManager(), "MyFragment");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I'm getting "@AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver." And I'm not able to Inject ViewModel in DialogFragment.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by replacing the **DialogFragment import** and its working fine;

Old Import:
import **android.app.DialogFragment;**

New Import:
import **androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;**

Comment: I am still having this issue.  All of my imports are androidx

Comment: @petestmart Did you manage to fix the problem?
I'm having the same issue with Activities, and in the end it's using import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity, which should be the right one.

Comment: @latsson unfortunately, no. I had to abandon the Hilt migration project I was working on for something more urgent and never came back to it.

Comment: @petestmart I managed to resolve my issue, but sadly now I don't remember what I did :/

Comment: @latsson modify activity file in any way